Caching application data
I am buliding a web application which is a guard management tool, The application has data like
Name
Apartment Name
Salary
Advance taken
DayShiftCount
NightShiftCount
Date of Joining
Contact
Advance History
Patrol history
in the profile section of the GUARD PROFILE, based on which there are graphs created. Now these values don't update that frequently, the attendance related data updates once in a day and the patrol history updates about 3 times a day.
Should I be caching such data before hand before I get into any trouble or is it a good practice to optimize it only when we face a problem. I currently cache values like the GuardId which stays persistent thhought the session.
If I choose to cache this data on the browser and reuse it everytime I refresh the page, I can reduce load on the server to fetch this data from database everytime but I'm not sure how to get any info on if the data is updated.Ican update the cached value on a hourly basis, but is there a way to do it differently. Is it the right approach to go forward with or is there any alternative to achieve this something like server caching.
PS : It might be a simple thing, I am a beginner in this field trying to understand how things work.
I believe that to achieve this, I can have a last updated field in the database to check if the data is updated, but this again is a dependency on server, so I see that I am not achieving anything here since again we are making an API call.
Can anyone please help me with where I should get started with, any documentation or reerence helps.
Thanks in advance!!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
